# How to change router URL prefix to pass double lookup field in Django Rest Framework (DRF)

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-urls

I want to set URLs for comments of special blog post. So I need the ID of that blog, but I don't know how to change the prefix.

url.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter

from .views import BlogViewSet, CommentViewSet

router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('blog', BlogViewSet, basename='blog')
router.register('blog/<int:id>/comments', CommentViewSet, basename='comments')
urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(router.urls)),

]
```

Comment: What is getting doubled or locked up in your code?  It isn't clear to me what the error is.

Comment: @stephen-ostermiller according the code for example i wan to have list of comments of a blog in a url such as "blog/1/commets/ and get the deitail of first comment of first blog in url "blog/1/comments/1" but i dont know how

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by double lock up.

Comment: " <int:id>" this part is lockup in drf and this is for blog but i want to have an other for comments at the same time, for answer this question you must be django and drf developer @stephen-ostermiller

Comment: Do you mean "look up"?

Comment: @stephen-ostermiller i'm sorry yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use drf-nested-routers package to do this.
[drf-nested-router](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
from rest_framework_nested import routers

from .views import BlogViewSet, CommentViewSet


router = SimpleRouter()
router.register('blog', BlogViewSet, basename='blog')
domains_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'blog', lookup='blog')
domains_router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet, basename='comments')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('', include(domains_router.urls)),

]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).